# How to use foreach for two associative arrays

Tags: php

So far the answers I have found is all about one associative array + one indexed array.
I got two associative arrays like the below:

```
$updates = array (
   array ( 'value' => $check_first ),
   array ( 'value' => $check_second )
);
$conditions = array (
   array ( 'name' => 'enable' ),
   array ( 'name' => 'picked' )
);
```

I wanna use foreach to update the wpdb database like below but it doesn't work, yeah I know foreach won't work like this, any other solution?

```
foreach ( $updates as $names_1 => $update ) {
   foreach( $conditions as $names_2 => $condition ) {
      $wpdb -> update ( $table_name, $update, $condition );
   }
}
```

Comment: Edit your question and show us how the raw sql query shoul look like

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Condition arrays' values can be arrays themselves and you can pass an associative array as a condition directly to `$wpdb->update()`. If you want every update to have its own conditions:

Array:

```
$updates = [
   [
      'fields' => [
         'field1' => 'value1',
         'field2' => 'value2',
      ],
      'conditions' => [
         'name' => ['enable', 'picked'],
      ],
   ],
];
```

Loop:

```
foreach ($updates as $update) {
   $wpdb->update($table_name, $update['fields'], $update['conditions']);
}
```

This is equivalent to the following SQL query:

```
UPDATE $table_name
SET field1 = 'value1', field2 = 'value2'
WHERE name IN ('enable', 'picked');
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got an error: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ']'`

Comment: @ctlpquudz Sorry, fixed the typos. You can try again :)

Comment: Sadly not working although I don't know why, you can try the code in a local environment.

Comment: @ctlpquudz Please, post the error message. Unfortunately, I do not currently have launched wordpress app.

Comment: There is no error, but the data is just not updated. It work if I hard code it without the foreach like `$wpdb->update($table_name, array ( 'value' => $check_first ), array ( 'name' => 'enable' ));` `$wpdb->update($table_name, array ( 'value' => $check_second ), array ( 'name' => 'picked' ));`

Comment: If you use example from my answer directly in your code it will not work because I specified test data in columns and wrote only one update. If you need my code to be the equivalent of the code in your last comment then you should divide one update into two and use correct column-value pairs.
I strongly recommend you to read about how arrays work in php: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Answer (score 0):

For someone who truly needs to iterate 2 arrays I did something like this.

The first one I used a regular `foreach` while the second one I used `array_slice` with a counter to go 1 by 1.

```
$updates = array (
   array ( 'value' => $check_first ),
   array ( 'value' => $check_second )
);
$conditions = array (
   array ( 'name' => 'enable' ),
   array ( 'name' => 'picked' )
);

$i=0;
foreach( $updates as $names_1 => $update )
{
    $condition = array_slice($conditions, $i++, 1, true);
    $wpdb -> update ( $table_name, $update, $condition['name'] );
}
```